# Haskell standard library function for transformations

Tags: haskell

Haskell has [Data.List.permutations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#permutations)

```
permutations "abc" == ["abc","bac","cba","bca","cab","acb"]
```

Is there a standard library function for transformations or do you need to roll your own?

```
transformations "ab" == ["aa","ab","ba","bb"]
```

The Ruby way is:

```
 x.repeated_permutation(x.length)
```

Comment: So, what do you mean by "transformations"? Permutations, variations or combinations?

Comment: I think `Control.Monad.sequence` is the function you want

Comment: All you [need](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations_with_repetitions#Haskell) [can](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations_with_repetitions#Haskell) [be](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#Haskell) [found](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#Haskell). I think if the solution on Rosetta didn't use any library, there is no standard way.

Comment: I meant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_(combinatorics) . They are permutations extended to allow copies. Yes, I think replicateM 2 x  might work, I'll try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`replicateM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) in the [`Control.Monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html) module:

```
replicateM 2 "ab"
-- ["aa","ab","ba","bb"]
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95e94de74995b585)

AFAIK they are permutations with repetitions from the alphabet `['a', 'b']`.

Comment: Sweet. How did you get that live demo button?

Comment: @ChadBrewbaker `<kbd>[Live demo](link to live demo)</kbd>`

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about Coliru.